# for loop that calls same function after previous iteration was completed

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I am trying to write a for loop that loops through an array of colors and calls another function which uses that array to change a button color.

Currently I have an array of three colors and I want the button to change to the first color then wait then turn back to white then change to the second color then wait then turn to white then change to the third color and wait and turn to white.

Right now I have two functions that change the color of the button then use setTimeout to wait 3 seconds before calling another function that changes the button back to white.

My thought was to just run this sequence in a for loop that loops through the colors.  The for loop seems to be firing but not waiting for the setTimeouts to finish from the previous iteration before continuing.  I think I may need a callback but am not sure how to proceed.

html:

```
<body>
  <button id="bigButton">Change Color</button>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
button{
  background-color: white;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#bigButton").on('click', function(){
    var a=["blue", "green", "red"];
    for(var m=0; m<a.length; m++){
        turnOn(a[m]);
    }
});

var timerID = null;
function turnOn (inputColor) {
    $("#bigButton").css("background-color", inputColor)
    clearTimeout (timerID);
    timerID = null;
    if (timerID === null) {
        timerID = setTimeout ("turnOff()", 3000);
    }
}
function turnOff () {
    $("#bigButton").css("background-color", "white")
    clearTimeout (timerID);
    timerID = null;
}
```

codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/zoeames/pen/pvqBYZ)

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous. Your loop instantly turns it blue, then green, then red. Then 3 second later it turns back to white 3 times.

Comment: Do you want all colours to be cycled through after only 1 click? Or should there be another click each time after the colour is reverted to white?

Comment: yes I want it to cycle through in 1 click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I updated a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ngkdp12/) with a working solution of this. Please let me know if this works.

The key was to move the color array out, and change which color to look at based off of an incrementing index:

```
var colors = ["blue", "green", "red"];
var currentIndex = 0;
var white = true;
$("#bigButton").on('click', function() {
  turnOn();
});

var timerID = null;

function turnOn() {
  if (!white) {
    white = true;
    inputColor = "white";
  } else {
    white = false;
    if (currentIndex === colors.length) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
    inputColor = colors[currentIndex];
    currentIndex++;
  }
  $("#bigButton").css("background-color", inputColor)
  console.log("color changed to ", inputColor);
  clearTimeout(timerID);
  timerID = null;
  if (timerID === null) {
    timerID = setTimeout("turnOff()", 3000);
  }
}

function turnOff() {
  $("#bigButton").css("background-color", "white")
  console.log("color changed to white");
  clearTimeout(timerID);
  timerID = null;
}
```

This is one way to solve this. You must click the button each time to have the color change.

Comment: how can i modify this so it automatically cycles through the array and changes the colors? without having to click each time?

Comment: Here is the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ngkdp12/1/). Use setInterval.